# Mouse not working on virtualbox 6.1.34

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Mouse click (both left and right) is not working on the screen although it can move and click icons on the left `Favorites` bar.

Host: Windows 11

Guest: VirtualBox Graphical User Interface Version 6.1.34 r150636 (Qt5.6.2)

Machine running on VirtualBox: Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My 2 cents - the virtualization module built into the Linux kernel (KVM) is a better way to go than 3rd party options (like VBox) on Nix hosts. So if you don't get an answer/want try something else, look up installing/using KVM/QEMU and VMM (Virtual Machine Manager) if you'd like a GUI front end.

Comment: Did you install the Virtual Box Guest Extensions in the Ubuntu Guest Machine?

Comment: @user1138 Thank you for the kind suggestion. I will try.

Comment: @John Yes, Virtual Box Guest Extension has been installed as well.

Comment: It finally worked by upgrading vm to 6.1.36. 
Thank you for all your answers!

Answer (score 5):

For Ubuntu 22.04 under VirtualBox 6.1.34, what has helped me was unchecking the box for Nested Paging in VirtualBox Settings -> System -> Acceleration

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is

> Virtual Box Settings -> System -> Pointing Device -> USB Multi-touch
> Tablet

I was facing this issue because earlier my pointing device was set to USB Tablet. Then I changed it to above mentioned option and it started working.

Comment: Worked for me as well, thanks!

Comment: Nice! That solved the problem :).

Answer (score 1):

It's the problem with Wayland.
Switch to XOrg on Ubuntu login screen and the problem with mouse will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but if you logout / login, it works normally. Send a Ctrl-Alt-Del to the guest and log out. Once you log in again, it works as it should. Didn't try any other solution.

Comment: Far from ideal, but indeed this worked for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can open a terminal window and change to superuser, do a

```
ps xua | grep drag
```

and then kill the two processes other than the "grep" process.

(Depending on some conditions not known to me, the drag&drop layer that the guest extensions put on top of the GUI and that capture all mouse activity can get into a condition where they still believe a drag operation is active while in reality it is not anymore. Killing the two processes with "drag" in their name will remove the guest extension's drag&drop layer, rendering the GUI usable again. Drag&Drop will still work the next time you use it.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please explain your answer

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by uncheck and then check
"Input > Mouse Integration"
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try to rise the video memory of your VM in settings -> Display -> Screen
I faced the same issue, with the same configuration, and it worked for me